# Enable GPO Administrative Templates System Node

Tags: windows-server-2008, group-policy

How do I enable access to the system node in the group policy management editor in Server 2008 R2?  It is available in the local group policy editor.

[image: Group Policy Management Editor]

[image: Local Group Policy Editor]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With 2008 and later, the AGPM console looks for ADMX & ADML files on the sysvol share. Those files are not present until they are manually copied. You can do that with these commands:

```
xcopy %systemroot%\PolicyDefinitions\* %logonserver%\sysvol\%userdnsdomain%\policies\PolicyDefinitions\ 
xcopy %systemroot%\PolicyDefinitions\EN-US\* %logonserver%\sysvol\%userdnsdomain%\policies\PolicyDefinitions\EN-US\
```

Described in more detail here
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Bb530196.aspx